# Use a collection to handle a lot of rows of data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 70 rows of data that must be entered into a database table.

Parameters range are @P01 to @P02 , @P03 .... @P77 , will call the procedure and store it into the table.

I tried this method. The data was successfully inserted, but I don't think it's particularly good code.

```
private int Execute_NonQuery(string value1, string value2, string value3, string value4,
                             string value5, string value6, string value7)
{
    int result = (int)ExcuteResult.Fail;

    try
    {
        _sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERTCSV_S", this.Connection);
        _sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]
                {
                    new SqlParameter("@P01", value1),
                    new SqlParameter("@P02", value2),
                    new SqlParameter("@P03", value3),
                    new SqlParameter("@P04", value4),
                    new SqlParameter("@P05", value5),
                    new SqlParameter("@P06", value6),
                    new SqlParameter("@P07", value7),
                                 ....... 
                    new SqlParameter("@P77", value7),
                };
                
        _sqlCmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);

        result = _sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("{0}\r\nMessage : {1}", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
        MessageBox.Show(msg);

        if (CheckConnection() == false)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The procedure is:

```
INSERT INTO TB_REFLOWER_TEMP ([WORK_DATE], [EQUIP_LEVEL], [EQUIP_ID],
                              [FILE_NAME], [MODE], [(kWh)], [(kW)]
                              .....) 
VALUES (@P01, @P02, @P03,
        @P04, @P05, @P06, @P07,
        ...)
```

Is there a way to reduce the code using collection?

Comment: Use a Table-Valued Parameter.

Comment: Show us the definition of `PROCEDURE INSERTCSV_S`.

Comment: The content has been modified.

Comment: Oh, so each parameter corresponds to a separate column? and not a separate row?

Comment: YES , It corresponds to a separate column.

Comment: I think you should redesign your database - having 77 `nvarchar` columns strongly suggests your table design is denormalized...

Comment: I created a table temporarily. My question is about how to readability the function code.

Comment: Use a table-valued parameter - but you can't use a TVP to map rows-to-columns.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that many paramaters if you are inserting a single row that wide. Why the table is so wide is another question, it implies there is probably denormalization. You should also specify the types and lengths of the parameters properly. Also `_sqlCmd` and `this.Connection` implies you are caching connections and commands. Do not do this, they need to be disposed with `using`.

Comment: You can pass a collection of values into your method and loop over them. If they are all the same type, you could use a `List<string>`. But having parameters named `P0` ..`P77` will earn you the undying ire of your maintenance programmers. Consider giving the meaningful names and passing a `Dictionary <string, string>` instead. Finally, a still better solution is to use _Dapper_ and pass an anonymous object in to represent your parameters

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use `SqlDataAdapter` and [batch operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performing-batch-operations-using-dataadapters). This allow to reduce roundtrips versus the server creating batch of desired size.

In detail you could create a `DataTable` object, create a `SqlDataAdapter` with the `InsertCommand`, set the `UpdateBatchSize` and let ADO.NET do the rest.

Something like this:

```cs
// create the data table
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));


// add 3 rows
dt.Rows.Add(1, "A", "Description A");
dt.Rows.Add(1, "B", "Description B");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "A", "Description A");

// use adapter to insert data (doesn't matter the 
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id = 1", conn)) {
    
    adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERTCSV_S", conn);
    adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@P0", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Col1");
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@P1", SqlDbType.NChar, 1, "Col2"); 
    // ... 
    
    adapter.BatchSize = batchSize;
    
    adapter.Update(dt);
}
```

Comment: `DbDataAdapter`'s "Batch" functionality is hardly an improvement here - what it means in practice is that it will fire-off dozens of RBAR `INSERT` statements, which is pretty atrocious, imo. It doesn't even generate multi-row `INSERT` statements.

Comment: I answered in relation to the request to use a stored procedure. Obviously if the requirement changes the solution could be more efficient. I don't know if in this case the user could use a multi-row `INSERT` and avoid the stored procedure.